# How to clean up aptitude output?

Tags: virtualbox, aptitude

Every time I use the CLI to install something with aptitude I get this output:

```
warning, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 60509 package 'virtualbox-3.0':
 error in Version string '3.0.10-54097_Ubuntu_karmic': invalid character in revision number
warning, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 60510 package 'virtualbox-3.0':
 error in Config-Version string '3.0.10-54097_Ubuntu_karmic': invalid character in revision number
warning, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 64255 package 'virtualbox-3.0':
 error in Version string '3.0.10-54097_Ubuntu_karmic': invalid character in revision number
Selecting previously deselected package libppl7.
(Reading database ... 328408 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libppl7 (from .../libppl7_0.10.2-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
...
...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
warning, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 60773 package 'virtualbox-3.0':
 error in Version string '3.0.10-54097_Ubuntu_karmic': invalid character in revision number
warning, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 60774 package 'virtualbox-3.0':
 error in Config-Version string '3.0.10-54097_Ubuntu_karmic': invalid character in revision number
warning, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 64482 package 'virtualbox-3.0':
 error in Version string '3.0.10-54097_Ubuntu_karmic': invalid character in revision number
Setting up libppl7 (0.10.2-7ubuntu1) ...
...
```

How can I fix this? I have even removed virtualbox, but this output still persists.

There is this on the Ubuntu forums http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1578934 but it did not work for me (Which step in the process given there actually fixes this problem?!).

EDIT: The installation process itself works, but these lines are cluttering up the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type the following in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
```

You need to edit the file and remove the offensive characters manually. Make a backup of the existing file.

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.bad

gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Go to line **60773**, **60774** and **64482**. The problem seems to be that the underscore has become at some point an illegal character in Debian package names. Edit the offending lines, change all underscores to tildes(**~**) will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you have already purged the package(s), see also `dpkg --clear-avail`.  You'll then need to regenerate the list of available packages with `dselect update`.  Note: these steps presume that you've removed the deb{,-src} entr{y,ies} from /etc/apt/sources*